# Loading a CSV into multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, csv

So what i need to do is load a csv file to a JTable with dynamic array(anywhere between 2 and 6 values), first i came up with this solution:

```
private String[][] Load()
{
    try {
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FilePath");
        try{
            String line;
            final ArrayList<String> List1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            final ArrayList<String> List2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            final ArrayList<String> List3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                final String[] parse = line.split(",");
                List1.add(parse[0]);
                List2.add(parse[1]);
                List3.add(parse[2]);
            }

            final ArrayList[] lists = new ArrayList[]{List1, List2, List3};
            final String[][] temp = new String[List1.size()][List1.get(0).split(",").length];

            for(int x = 0 ; x < temp.length ; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0 ; y < temp[x].length ; y++)
                {
                    temp[x][y] = (String) lists[y].get(x);
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }finally
        {
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

which i thought was horrible, so i came up with this solution:

```
private String[][] Load()
{

    try
    {
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FilePath"));
        try
        {
            final List<String> raw = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                raw.add(line);

            final String[][] temp = new String[raw.size()][raw.get(0).split(",").length];
            for(int x = 0 ; x < raw.size() ; x++)
            {
                final String[] parse = raw.get(x).split(",");
                for(int y = 0 ; y < temp[x].length ; y++)
                {
                    temp[x][y] = parse[y];
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }finally
        {
            br.close();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

but i'm not so sure about that either, both of them work just fine so really all i'm asking is, how would you do it?

Edit: can't really use external libs with this project.

Comment: CSV may become more complicated of what it appears to be. I would use a 3rd party API (I think Apache has one).

Comment: @SJuan76 with the project i'm currently working on i can't really use external libs, otherwise i definitely would.